# Error: timed out waiting for the condition during long helm tests

Tags: kubernetes-helm

How can I force helm to wait for the end of the test suite?

```
 $ helm test $RELEASE --namespace $NAMESPACE
 NAME: myproject-test
 LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Feb 14 10:43:04 2020
 NAMESPACE: myproject-test-vjuh-init-helm
 STATUS: deployed
 REVISION: 1
 TEST SUITE:     myproject-test-django-test
 Last Started:   Fri Feb 14 10:45:53 2020
 Last Completed: Fri Feb 14 10:50:54 2020
 Phase:          Failed
 NOTES:
 Deployed
 Error: timed out waiting for the condition
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `--timeout 30m` or longer to your helm command:

```
helm test $RELEASE --namespace $NAMESPACE --timeout 30m
```

As stated in the manual `helm test --help`:

```
--timeout duration   time to wait for any individual Kubernetes operation (like Jobs for hooks) (default 5m0s)
```